# Meaning of SASS (SCSS) plus sign and ampersand syntax ( + & ) to the right of a selector?

Tags: css, sass

I am looking at a SCSS somebody else wrote, and I notice a selector with a plus and ampersand immediately to the right.

```
.listing-feature {
   &__summary {
       .feature-title+& {
          color: #f00;
       }
   }
}
```

What does this do?  I tried compiling the project, but I can't find what this compiles into.

Would it be something like this?

```
.feature-title + .listing-feature__summary {
    color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: `+` simply is just the regular *adjacent sibling combinator` from CSS. `&` in SCSS is replaced with the selector your SCSS block has built up at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an online SASS compiler and plugged this code in and got.

```
.feature-title + .listing-feature__summary {
  color: #f00;
}
```

This ends up being a sibling selector.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator

Answer (score 3):

The `&` is just shorthand for the selector (`.listing-feature__summary` in your case).

The plus means that every `.listing-feature__summary` class that follows the `.feature-title` class will be affected by the styles added.

Comment: I don't think your interpretation of & is correct.  If the & was on the left of __summary, it would be .listing-feature__summary as you said.

Comment: `&` is the current selector, so that would mean that since the parent of `.feature-title+&` is `&__summary`, which would make the `&`, in the lowest child selector, be `&__summary`, which is equal to `.listing-feature__summary`. So, in your case, every element with the class `.listing-feature__summary` will be edited if it falls within the boundaries of `.feature-title` in your HTML.